# Running count distinct

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to see how the cumulative number of subscribers changed over time based on unique email addresses and date they were created. Below is an example of a table I am working with.

[image]

I am trying to turn it into the table below. Email 1@gmail.com was created twice and I would like to count it once. I cannot figure out how to generate the **Running count distinct** column.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the database? "sql" is a standard, but all databases have slightly different variants of it. Snowflake also does not help, it is a dw design pattern. and, *sigh*, please don't use images of data, text tables are superior e.g. https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 3):

I would usually do this using `row_number()`:

```
select date, count(*),
       sum(count(*)) over (order by date),
       sum(sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end)) over (order by date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by email order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by date
order by date;
```

This is similar to the version using `lag()`.  However, I get nervous using lag if the same email appears multiple times on the same date.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the total count and cumulative count is straight forward. To get the cumulative distinct count, use `lag` to check if the email had a row with a previous date, and set the flag to 0 so it would be ignored during a running sum.

```
select distinct dt
      ,count(*) over(partition by dt) as day_total
      ,count(*) over(order by dt) as cumsum
      ,sum(flag) over(order by dt) as cumdist
from (select t.*
            ,case when lag(dt) over(partition by email order by dt) is not null then 0 else 1 end as flag   
      from tbl t
     ) t
```

**[`DEMO HERE`](https://rextester.com/KLU49400)**

Comment: You might need to sort the output to match OP's expected result at 100%

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not uses `sum over`, neither `lag`... And does produces the correct results.

Hence it could appear as simpler to read and to maintain.

```
select 
    t1.date_created,
    (select count(*) from my_table where date_created = t1.date_created) emails_created,
    (select count(*) from my_table where date_created <= t1.date_created) cumulative_sum,
    (select count( distinct email)  from my_table where date_created <= t1.date_created) running_count_distinct
from 
    (select distinct date_created from my_table) t1    
order by 1
```